# Pushing objects to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have three html buttons on my page:

```
<button class="timespanbutton" value="1">1</button>
<button class="timespanbutton" value="2">2</button>
<button class="timespanbutton" value="3">3</button>
```

Now I want to create an array, containing an object for each button:

```
var timespanObject = {}, timespanArray = [];
countSpecificFacilitySlotAmount = 3;

$('.timespanbutton').each(function() {
 slotName = "timespanbutton" + $(this).val();
  timespanObject.timespanName = slotName;
    timespanArray.push(timespanObject);
});
```

to get an array containing 3 objects with each created name like

```
timespanbutton1
timespanbutton2
timespanbutton3
```

I really do not know, what I am doing wrong, but all three get the name

```
timespanbutton3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Well you are changing the reference of same object**

> Understand with example how it works

```js
let a ={};
let b = a;
a.name = 'xyz';
a.name = 'abc';
console.log(a.name)
console.log(b.name)
```

So here in above example we have two variables a and b. a is an object.

1. Every time we update name the last value will be overwritten by new one.
2. When we assign a object to any other variable it is assigned as reference not a copy.So as we change the value of a you can see the change if you print b.

**Working version of your code below**

```js
var timespanArray = [];
countSpecificFacilitySlotAmount = 3;

$('.timespanbutton').each(function() {
 slotName = "timespanbutton" + $(this).val();
 var timespanObject = {};
  timespanObject.timespanName = slotName;
    timespanArray.push(timespanObject);
});

console.log(timespanArray)
```

```html
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button class="timespanbutton" value="1">1</button>
<button class="timespanbutton" value="2">2</button>
<button class="timespanbutton" value="3">3</button>
```

Comment: Bingo! This is the right answer, because it explains why it contains same names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare slotname variable in loop, it reference in context and having last value all time.

So try this instead

```
$('.timespanbutton').each(function() {
    var slotName = "timespanbutton" + $(this).val(); // new var declare
    var timespanObject.timespanName = slotName;
    timespanArray.push(timespanObject);
});
```